# Single Table inheritance Active admin model mapping issue rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have created a multiple user with single table inheritance here are my models

```
# user.rb 

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is user model and all other model are inherit from user in database their is one model which store both type of user and also saving their types

```
# customer.rb

class Customer < User
end

# space_owner.rb

class SpaceOwner < User
end
```

**when I map these in `active_admin` rails 4 is shows me an error **

```
Showing /home/rabnawaz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bundler/gems/activeadmin-0a5a15b88bff/app/views/active_admin/resource/index.html.arb where line #2 raised:

undefined method `chain' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #709):
  def chain
    @chain ||= begin
      a = source_reflection.chain
      b = through_reflection.chain
      chain = a + b
      chain[0] = self # Use self so we don't lose the information from :source_type
```

This is the error I get when I create `active_admin` files to display users

Can you please give me a solution?

Here are my routes for devise which i m using to create multiple users

```
devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

devise_for :customers, :controllers => { 
    :registrations=>"customers/registrations", 
    :passwords=>"customers/passwords"
  },:skip => :sessions
  devise_for :space_owners, :controllers => { 
    :registrations=>"space_owners/registrations", 
    :passwords=>"space_owners/passwords"
  },:skip => :sessions
```

Comment: The error message says that nil class doesn't have chain method, which could mean that one of  source_reflection or through_reflection is not defined at the point you call chain on it.

Comment: thanks
i just used this and problem is solved
 config.filters = false

Comment: @RabnawazJansherBadozai Disabling filters is not a fix. The bug is reported here though https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3957

Answer (score 1):

To give this an answer quoting from https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3957:

> After some research I figured out that this error appears when active_record can't automatically infer the name for a nested
> association. Workaround to handle this could for instance be using
> `through` on nested associations.

It is also not clear from your question if you did register the User sub-classes with ActiveAdmin.